# CLI/C++ How to store more than 15 digit float number?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, floating-point, c++-cli, euclidean-distance

For a school project, I have a simple program, which compares 20x20 photos. I put 20 photos, and then i put 21th photo, which is compared to existing 20, and pops up the answer, which photo i did insert (or which one is most similar). The problem is, my teacher wanted me to use nearest neighbour algorithm, so i am counting distance from every photo. I got everything working, but the thing is, if photos are too similar, i got the problem with saying which one is closer to my one. For example i get these distances with 2 different photos (well, they are ALMOST the same):

```
0 distance: 1353.07982026191
1 distance: 1353.07982026191
```

It is 15 digits already, and i am using `double` type. I was reading that `long double` is the same. Is there any "easy" way to store numbers with more than 15 digits and do math on them?

I count distance using Euclidean distance
[image]
I just need to be more precise, or thats limit i probably wont pass here, and i should talk to my teacher i cant compare such similar photos?

Comment: You don't need to take the square root, because you can just compare the squared differences instead, for the same answer. Also you surely don't need more than 15 significant figures here: if two pictures are the same to this precision, treat them as equally close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this: gmplib.org

There's a guide how to install this library on this site too.

And here's article about floats: http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Floats.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-Floats

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use an algebraic approach.

Let us assume that you are trying to calcuate if vector **x** is closer to **a** or **b**. What you need to calculate is the sign of

d<sup>2</sup>(**x**, **a**) - d<sup>2</sup>(**x**, **b**)

Which becomes (I'll omit some passages for brevity)

[image]

and then

[image]

Which only contains differences between values which should be very similar. Summing over such small values should yield a better precision than working on the aggregate.

Comment: A note on my last remark: you are actually adding two numbers of same magnitude (-> no loss in precision), and multiplying by a presumably much smaller one (-> no loss in precision on machines using the IEEE representation).